# Android: Previous page button, without losing data

Tags: android, android-activity, android-button

I have need some help to achieve the following:

When I click on my previous-button I want the application to go to the previous page without losing my data. I already added the previous-button to the application, but when I click it my application goes to the main page instead of the previous page.

**My code:**

```
 Button next,previous;
        next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.work_next);
        previous = (Button)findViewById(R.id.work_previous);
        previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intentSignUP = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), filldetails.class);
                startActivity(intentSignUP);
                finish();
            }
        });

        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                boolean allValues = true;

                String comp="",desg="",fromdate="",todate="",role_d="",technologies_used="";

                if(companyName.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    allValues = false;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter all the fields",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    comp= companyName.getText().toString();
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter all the fields",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                if(designation.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    allValues = false;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter all the fields",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    desg = designation.getText().toString();
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter all the fields",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                if(fromDate.getText().toString().length()<8 || fromDate.getText().toString().length()>10 ||fromDate.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    allValues = false;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter valid Date",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    fromdate = fromDate.getText().toString();
                }
                if(toDate.getText().toString().length()<8 || toDate.getText().toString().length()>10 ||toDate.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    allValues = false;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter valid Date",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                   todate = toDate.getText().toString();
                }

                if(role_desc.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    allValues = false;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter all the fields",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    role_d = role_desc.getText().toString();
                }

                if(technologiesUsed.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    allValues = false;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter all the fields",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    technologies_used = technologiesUsed.getText().toString();
                }
                if(allValues)
                {
                    Intent moveToNext = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),skills.class);
                    moveToNext.putExtra("comp_name",comp);
                    moveToNext.putExtra("desc",desg);
                    moveToNext.putExtra("role_d",role_d);
                    moveToNext.putExtra("from_date",fromdate);
                    moveToNext.putExtra("to_date",todate);
                    moveToNext.putExtra("technologies_used",technologies_used);
                    moveToNext.putExtra("iscurrent",isCurrent.isChecked());
                    moveToNext.putExtra("aboutme",getIntent().getStringExtra("aboutme"));
                    moveToNext.putExtra("address",getIntent().getStringExtra("address"));
                    startActivity(moveToNext);

                    finish();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please provide all values", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to start the activity to go to previous activity (if you haven't called `finish()` on that), just close the current activity and it will go to previous activity and data will be intact.

Change your `onClick` method of `previous` button like this

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    finish();
}
```

**Note:** If you have closed the previous activity by calling `finish()` then remove that code, otherwise data will not be intact without modifying your code in that activity.